# Send array from android and receive at PhP server using Volley

Tags: php, android, arrays, android-volley

Hi I want to send an array of String value to PhP server and PhP decode and store them in PhP variable

Here is my code at android studio

```
private void getEventDetailRespond(RequestQueue requestQueue) {
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (int i=0; i <eventIDBeacon.size();i++){
                params.put(Config.EVENT_ID, eventIDBeacon.get(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Creating a JSONObject request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.DATA_URL,params.toString(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject respond) {
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(Beacon_MainActivity.this,"eventDetail respond "+respond.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                eventArray = new JSONArray();
                                eventDetail = new ArrayList<>();
                                eventArray = respond.getJSONArray("result");
                                eventDetail = getEventDetail(eventArray);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(Beacon_MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data event Detail: " +error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                );

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private ArrayList getEventDetail(JSONArray j) {
        ArrayList event = new ArrayList();
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the event to array list
                event.add(json.getString(Config.EVENT_TITLE));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (event.isEmpty()) eventView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else {
            if (beacons.size()!=0) {
                checkIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                eventView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Beacon_MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, event));
            }else {
                checkIn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                eventView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
        return event;
    }
```

And to recieve from PhP size, this is my code

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

// decoding the json array
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);


$eventID = $post['EventID'];



require_once('dbconnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT EventID, EventTitle, EventDesc, EventTime FROM Event WHERE EVENTID = '$eventID'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();


 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,array(
            'EventID'=>$row['EventID'],
            'EventTitle'=>$row['EventTitle'],
            'EventDesc'=>$row['EventDesc'],
            'EventTime'=>$row['EventTime']
        ));
    }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result), 256);

    mysqli_close($con);


}
```

It seem not to work as I can not send and array to PhP server and decode it on PhP server. any help is much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override volley's getParams method inside your getEventDetailRespond method

```
 @Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
 JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        for (int i=0; i <eventIDBeacon.size();i++){
            params.put(Config.EVENT_ID, eventIDBeacon.get(i));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return params;
};
```

that's the way to send params using Volley library..
in your case you have to create this:

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<>> params = new          
       HashMap<String,ArrayList<>>();
```

where array list is your desired list

Comment: thanks a lot but how to decode on PhP server and store the value into PhP array?

Comment: do you want to store "$post" variable into PhP array?

Comment: Yes my objective is to send ArrayList (eventBeacon) to PhP server and store into local PhP variable. I'm still dont know how to send and receive and array (1 variable can)

Comment: after that your $post variable contains a json array...you can use var_dump($post) to log what has been sended to server

Comment: Thanks a lot where to put var_dump($post) and how to see log?

Comment: inside your php script..to see the log if your are using firefox go to developer-network-and after you make the volley request you can see the log displayed on the "Network" tab..

Comment: Do u have the link i come https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ but dont see any network tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96773/discussion-between-tsiro-and-le-khanh-vinh).

Answer (score 1):

First in your Object in ArrayList: create JSONObjectmethod name as getJSONObject, like this

```
public class EstimateObject {
String id, name, qty, price, total;
public EstimateObject(String id, String name, String qty, String price, String total, int position)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.price = price;
    this.total =total;
    this.position = position;
}
 public JSONObject getJSONObject() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("Id", id);
        obj.put("Name", name);
        obj.put("Qty",qty);
        obj.put("Price", price);
        obj.put("Total", total);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Aftrer Here is how I converted it,in my activity

```
    JSONObject JSONestimate = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

        try {
            JSONestimate.put("data:" + String.valueOf(i + 1), items.get(i).getJSONObject());
            myarray.put(items.get(i).getJSONObject());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d("JSONobject: ", JSONestimate.toString());
    Log.d("JSONArray : ", myarray.toString());
```

Here i converted both type JSONObject and JSONArray.

After in

```
map.put("jsonarray",myarray.toString());
```

And in php

```
$json = $_POST['jsonarray'];
$json_array = json_decode($json,true);
```