# How can I insert my Arraylist in mysql with Volley?

Tags: php, arraylist, android-volley

At present I can insert string values individually into my Mysql db using Volley, like this :

I create two strings :

```
public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
String phoneNo;
```

And then further on in my Volley class :

```
@Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, phoneNo);
                return map;
```

And then on my PHP side something like :

```
    $CheckContact = $_POST['phonenumber'];
etc....
```

So if I specify `phonenumber` as for example 1234567890 this will be inserted into my db.

How should the Volley code above look like if I want to post a whole arraylist of phone numbers into my db in one go ?

I have an arraylist, `alContacts`, which looks something like this :

```
[+12345, +34567, +65221, etc....]
```

I want to insert all the numbers in my db. How would the Volley code go for this ?

I think my PHP code will be something along the lines of :

```
foreach($_POST['phonenumber' as $CheckContact]
```

But I'll worry about that after the Volley code.

Answer (score 3):

Firts you send arraylist with key,value pair,

After in php side,

```
$json = $_POST['phonenumber']; /* this is arraylist name */
$json_array = json_decode($json,true)
$count = count($json_array );

 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
      { 

       $phonenumber=  $arr_obj[$i]->phonenumber; /*phonenumber is key of phonenuber value inside arraylist */

       if(!empty($phonenumber))
       {

        $insert = " insert into table_name(phonenumber) values('$phonenumber')";
        $result = mysql_query($insert);
      }
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037810/send-array-from-android-and-receive-at-php-server-using-volley/42000840#42000840) you can understand how to create jsonobject and send arraylist to sever.

Answer (score 1):

To send all values in single parameter to server use JSONObject.Create a json object using all key-value.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
      arr[i]="questionId_"+i+"_"+"ans_"+i;
      jsonObject.put("params_"+i,arr[i]);
    }
   @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map.put("KEY_PHONENUMBER", jsonObject.toString());
      return map
    }
```

and then using php

```
    $CheckContact = $_POST['alContacts'];

    foreach($_POST['phonenumber' as $CheckContact]{
      //insert into db
     }
```

Edit: 
I think u have an array and u can store array value in json object.

```
  for(int i=1;i<=alContacts.length;i++)
    {
      jsonObject.put("params_"+i,alContacts.length[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how the for(int i = 1 etc...arr[i]);} applies in my case. Is it relevant ?